# Android app daily **uninstalls**, how is it calculated from developer console?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Any idea as to how android developer console figures out daily uninstalls ?
My hunch -

- through GCM ping failure
- google play service that can send back package removed broadcast receiver

Any broad and non-trivial architectural pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask how to know daily removed app number from devices or how does Google know the removed devices?

Comment: How does Google know the removed devices? We get the uninstalled numbers from play developer console dropdown